# Why are all of my event subscriptions applying to all instances of the publishers?

Tags: c#, events, xna

(Aka, why is my event running 2106 copies of the subscribed method when I only added it once?)

In the add method for adding a set of blocks to the world (called asynchronously):

```
public virtual void AddBlocks(IBlockCoordinate[] positions, Block[] blocks)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
        {
            blocks[i].Coordinate = positions[i];
            blocks[i].ParentContainer = this;
            //THIS LINE is called on average about 2000 times.
            //this is where the event gets assigned
            blocks[i].Destroyed += new EventHandler(block_Destroyed);
        }
        if (geometry != null)
        {
            List<IBlockCoordinate> list = new List<IBlockCoordinate>();
            foreach(IBlockCoordinate pos in positions)
                list.Add(pos);
            geometry.CreateBlocks(list.ToArray(), blocks);
            for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
                components.Add((BlockClumpCoordinate)positions[i], blocks[i]);
        }
        else 
            for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
                if(!components.ContainsKey((BlockClumpCoordinate)positions[i]))
                    components.Add((BlockClumpCoordinate)positions[i], blocks[i]);
        foreach (Block block in blocks)
        {
            AddToSpecialLists(block);
        }
        FindMaxRadius();
        OnBlockAdded();
    }
```

(see commented line)
So, do I just not understand events?  Why is it that, even though I specifically only add the subscription to each block once, if I destroy any block it calls the method once for every block in the world?  Am I missing something obvious here?  It's as if methods subscribed to events are not specific to an object's instance, but to the object itself (thus all instances of Block share the same event handler, that would NOT work for me).

In case I haven't been clear enough: The above method is called during my loading phase asynchronously.  It creates a bunch of blocks in a specific place.  It sets each of those blocks to call a method when their Destroyed event is fired.  Yet when I destroy any one of the blocks, it calls that method around 2000 times; one for each block in the world.

Edit: here's some more code.  I think this covers all mention of the Destroyed event.

**In Block.cs:**

```
public event EventHandler Destroyed;
    protected void OnDestroyed()
    {
        if (Destroyed != null)
        {
            Destroyed(this, null); //when the run is broken here, I can see that Destroyed has an invocationCount of ~1000-2000
        }
    }
[...]
public virtual void Damage(float amt)
    {
        health -= amt;
        if (health < 0)
            OnDestroyed(); //this line is only called once per destroyed block
    }
```

**in BlockClump.cs (the class which defines a group of blocks)**

```
public virtual void AddBlocks(IBlockCoordinate[] positions, Block[] blocks)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
        {
            blocks[i].Coordinate = positions[i];
            blocks[i].ParentContainer = this;
            blocks[i].Destroyed += new EventHandler(block_Destroyed);
            SuperContent.Instance.debugCount++; //after all loading is finished, this static int counter reads ~2000.  That represents the number of times this code block is run for the entire game.
        }

        [... more logistics of adding blocks to the geometric model]

    }
[...]
void block_Destroyed(object sender, EventArgs e) //this function is called thousands of times with each single event fire
{
    Vector3 position = (BlockClumpCoordinate)(sender as Block).Coordinate;
    position = Vector3.Transform(position, world);
    (sender as Block).Regenerate();
    ContainingSpace.AddSpaceBlock(new SpaceBlock(   //a space block is the broken 'item' block
        (sender as Block).Clone(),
        position,
        .1f));
    components.Remove((BlockClumpCoordinate)(sender as Block).Coordinate);
}
```

The AddBlocks method is called on a separate thread from the main game during the loading phase.

Comment: Can you add the source code for the IBlock implementation. or else it is hard to guess what is going on.

Comment: Either, 1) you are calling the event handler multiple times, or 2) you are calling AddBlocks multiple times (adding multiple event handlers to the same block). Based on the code you posted, there is no telling.

Comment: I am only calling the event once, I checked.  If I break the program when the event is fired and step through from there, I step through the block_Destroyed method over and over without ever stepping through the event firing again.  Also, if I inspect the Destroyed event during the break, I can see that the invocationCount of the event is upwards of 2000 on average.

I don't think posting the Block source code will help, given that the only relevant code is the one-line event firing upon a specific condition (which only happens once, I checked).

Comment: I will edit the main post with any relevant code I can scrape together asap.

Comment: Currently investigating some of my partner's code.  I don't think he used block cloning properly.  All of these blocks *might* be the same instance, which would mean I keep adding events to the same blocks.  Thanks for replying, but this might just be his fault! xD

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to unrelated code.  Sorry for pulling the trigger and asking a question when I hadn't explored all options.  The issue lay with some of the code my partner did when he wrote the block creation stuff.  To boost efficiency he cached all blocks the first time they were created and referenced the cached block to create a new block of that type.  Except that he didn't clone the block, he just returned the reference, so all dirt blocks were in reality the same instance.  Thus, I added one method to the dirt block's event for every 'new' block I thought I was creating.

This also explains a lot of the other bugs I've been hitting lately!  So I'm going to fire him.  Except not really, because that would strain our roommate relationship.  Also the code is from before we implemented the cloning, so...

Anyways, thanks all.